# How Function<T, R> works internally

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am trying to understand how apply() works in this below scenario

```
        Function<Integer,Integer> f  = x -> x+1;
        Function<Integer,Integer> g  = x -> x*1;
        Function<Integer,Integer> h  = f.compose(g);
        System.out.println(h.apply(1));
```

I know, here first it calculates x+1 which is 1+1 = 2, and after that 2*1 = 2, and the result it prints is 2. but I did not understand how the apply() method works internally. because the Function h does not have implementation for abstract method apply(). It has simply invoked the default method compose(). So my question is, despite not having the implementation for abstract method apply(), how come Function h can invoke apply() method? Correct me If my understanding is wrong

Comment: `compose()` returns a lambda that implements `apply()`.

Comment: @shmosel but here it invoked h.apply(1) and it does not have implementation.

Comment: Of course it does. It's implemented in `compose()`.

Comment: `f.apply(x)` works kind of like `f(x)`

Comment: Incorrect order - g evaluates before f.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to look at the implementation:

```
default <V> Function<V, R> compose(Function<? super V, ? extends T> before) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(before);
    return (V v) -> apply(before.apply(v));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have a better understanding with a different choice of functions and test data.

As you have it `f(g(n))` equals `g(f(n))` which also equals `n+1` so you don't see the effect of the combination of the `f.compose(g)` which means definition of h as evaluate g then f.

Try instead this example which prints 38 not 50:

```
Function<Integer,Integer> f  = x -> x+3;
Function<Integer,Integer> g  = x -> x*5;
Function<Integer,Integer> h  = f.compose(g);
System.out.println(h.apply(7));
```